# How to change data structure (content types) on Strapi production server

Tags: strapi

I've got following problem. Lets assume that:

1. I have Strapi production environment with Content Type Builder switch off.
2. I have Strapi develop environment where I have Content Type Builder switch on and I can make changes to content types, add new, remove and whatever I want.
3. I made changes on dev. Content Type Builder automatically changed some js files and changed table in database.
4. I want to push these changes to production.

So what should I do? Should I just grab changed js file, put it on production and Strapi change database on its own? Or should I do something more then that?

Comment: You are right. Pushing the changes will have strapi update the content types. However permissions won't get updated. See [this github](https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/672#issuecomment-367258607) comment on how to migrate permissions. You may also take a look at [this documentation](https://docs-v3.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/developer-resources/cli/CLI.html#strapi-configuration-dump) on how to migrate configurations.

Comment: @Isfaaq thank you for such valuable comment :) I try to find any answer for a week from now. Could you tell me one more thing? By pushing changes you mean pushing only js files? Or js and manually change database?

Comment: You would typically keep your project in a git repository. By pushing I mean pushing all the latest changes in that repository to your sever.

Answer (score 0):

Is your code source-controlled (in SVN or GitHub)? If so, once your changes are tested locally and you've updated your models, etc... you should be able to commit and push those changes to the staging and/or production repositories for testing on the web.